# d3 zoom function issues in v4

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, svg

I am facing issues with the zoom function in D3 while using v4. It throws up an error saying that zoom.translate is not defined. I am mostly using the following code from this answer [d3 focus on node on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41905384/d3-focus-on-node-on-click), which worked perfectly for v3. However, as I was having issues with v3 as it has restrictions with data where the source and nodes are in the form of strings(instead of indices) [D3 JSON file with source and index as strings rather than indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41916842/d3-json-file-with-source-and-index-as-strings-rather-than-indices), I switched to v4.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.links line {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: 0.6;
}

.nodes circle {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>


var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height")
    active = d3.select(null);

var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1, 8])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);     

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

d3.json("graph.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended))
            .on("click", clicked);

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id; });

  simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

  function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  }
});

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}

function clicked(d){
  if (active.node() === this) return reset();
  active.classed("active", false);
  active = d3.select(this).classed("active", true);

  var bbox = active.node().getBBox(),
      bounds = [[bbox.x, bbox.y],[bbox.x + bbox.width, bbox.y + bbox.height]];

  var dx = bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0],
      dy = bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1],
      x = (bounds[0][0] + bounds[1][0]) / 2,
      y = (bounds[0][1] + bounds[1][1]) / 2,
      scale = Math.max(1, Math.min(8, 0.9 / Math.max(dx / width, dy / height))),
      translate = [width / 2 - scale * x, height / 2 - scale * y];

  svg.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .call(zoom.translate(translate).scale(scale).event);
} 

function reset() {
  active.classed("active", false);
  active = d3.select(null);

  svg.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .call(zoom.translate([0, 0]).scale(1).event);
} 

function zoomed() {
  console.log(d3.event)
  g.style("stroke-width", 1.5 / d3.event.scale + "px");
  g.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}        

</script>
```

I changed `d3.behaviour.zoom()` to `d3.zoom()` and even changed

```
.call(zoom.translate(translate).scale(scale).event);
```

to

```
.call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
        svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
}));
```

which throws up a strange error, error: unknown type: wheel

What would be the best way to go about overcoming this situation?

Comment: In [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41917020/5768908) to your previous question, I didn't say that you should upgrade to v4. Actually, I showed you how to do it using v3.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have the data in an array, but in a JSON file. Can it still be done?

Comment: Yes, it can. JSON is just syntax for storing data: your JSON probably contains an array.

Comment: It throws TypeError u.source.index is undefined:

d3.json("graph.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error; 
  
force.nodes(graph.nodes).links(graph.links).start();

 link = link.data(graph.links).enter().append("line").attr("class", "links");

 node = node.data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle").attr("class", "node").attr("r", 12).on("click", clicked);
    
    var nodeByName = d3.map(node, function(d) {
    return d.id;
});

link.forEach(function(d) {
    d.source = nodeByName.get(d.source);
    d.target = nodeByName.get(d.target);
}); 
});

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `d3` version 4 the correct way to do this is:

```
function clicked(d) {

    if (active.node() === this){
      active.classed("active", false);
      return reset();
    }

    active = d3.select(this).classed("active", true);

    svg.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .call(zoom.transform,
        d3.zoomIdentity
        .translate(width / 2, height / 2)
        .scale(8)
        .translate(-(+active.attr('cx')), -(+active.attr('cy')))
      );
  }
```

Where your zoom handler is:

```
function zoomed() {
  g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}
```

**Note**, I simplified the transform calculation from my previous answer. The bounds calculations there were not really necessary.

---

Full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  .links line {
    stroke: #aaa;
  }
  
  .nodes circle {
    pointer-events: all;
    stroke: none;
    stroke-width: 40px;
  }
  
  .active {
    fill: yellow;
  }
</style>
<svg width="960" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

  var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1 / 2, 4])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

  var g = svg.append("g");

  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) {
      return d.id;
    }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

  var graph = {
    "nodes": [{
      "id": "Myriel",
      "group": 1
    }, {
      "id": "Napoleon",
      "group": 1
    }, {
      "id": "Mlle.Baptistine",
      "group": 1
    }, {
      "id": "Mme.Magloire",
      "group": 1
    }, {
      "id": "CountessdeLo",
      "group": 1
    }, {
      "id": "Geborand",
      "group": 1
    }, {
      "id": "Champtercier",
      "group": 1
    }, {
      "id": "Cravatte",
      "group": 1
    }, {
      "id": "Count",
      "group": 1
    }, {
      "id": "OldMan",
      "group": 1
    }, {
      "id": "Labarre",
      "group": 2
    }, {
      "id": "Valjean",
      "group": 2
    }, {
      "id": "Marguerite",
      "group": 3
    }, {
      "id": "Mme.deR",
      "group": 2
    }, {
      "id": "Isabeau",
      "group": 2
    }, {
      "id": "Gervais",
      "group": 2
    }, {
      "id": "Tholomyes",
      "group": 3
    }, {
      "id": "Listolier",
      "group": 3
    }, {
      "id": "Fameuil",
      "group": 3
    }, {
      "id": "Blacheville",
      "group": 3
    }, {
      "id": "Favourite",
      "group": 3
    }, {
      "id": "Dahlia",
      "group": 3
    }, {
      "id": "Zephine",
      "group": 3
    }, {
      "id": "Fantine",
      "group": 3
    }, {
      "id": "Mme.Thenardier",
      "group": 4
    }, {
      "id": "Thenardier",
      "group": 4
    }, {
      "id": "Cosette",
      "group": 5
    }, {
      "id": "Javert",
      "group": 4
    }, {
      "id": "Fauchelevent",
      "group": 0
    }, {
      "id": "Bamatabois",
      "group": 2
    }, {
      "id": "Perpetue",
      "group": 3
    }, {
      "id": "Simplice",
      "group": 2
    }, {
      "id": "Scaufflaire",
      "group": 2
    }, {
      "id": "Woman1",
      "group": 2
    }, {
      "id": "Judge",
      "group": 2
    }, {
      "id": "Champmathieu",
      "group": 2
    }, {
      "id": "Brevet",
      "group": 2
    }, {
      "id": "Chenildieu",
      "group": 2
    }, {
      "id": "Cochepaille",
      "group": 2
    }, {
      "id": "Pontmercy",
      "group": 4
    }, {
      "id": "Boulatruelle",
      "group": 6
    }, {
      "id": "Eponine",
      "group": 4
    }, {
      "id": "Anzelma",
      "group": 4
    }, {
      "id": "Woman2",
      "group": 5
    }, {
      "id": "MotherInnocent",
      "group": 0
    }, {
      "id": "Gribier",
      "group": 0
    }, {
      "id": "Jondrette",
      "group": 7
    }, {
      "id": "Mme.Burgon",
      "group": 7
    }, {
      "id": "Gavroche",
      "group": 8
    }, {
      "id": "Gillenormand",
      "group": 5
    }, {
      "id": "Magnon",
      "group": 5
    }, {
      "id": "Mlle.Gillenormand",
      "group": 5
    }, {
      "id": "Mme.Pontmercy",
      "group": 5
    }, {
      "id": "Mlle.Vaubois",
      "group": 5
    }, {
      "id": "Lt.Gillenormand",
      "group": 5
    }, {
      "id": "Marius",
      "group": 8
    }, {
      "id": "BaronessT",
      "group": 5
    }, {
      "id": "Mabeuf",
      "group": 8
    }, {
      "id": "Enjolras",
      "group": 8
    }, {
      "id": "Combeferre",
      "group": 8
    }, {
      "id": "Prouvaire",
      "group": 8
    }, {
      "id": "Feuilly",
      "group": 8
    }, {
      "id": "Courfeyrac",
      "group": 8
    }, {
      "id": "Bahorel",
      "group": 8
    }, {
      "id": "Bossuet",
      "group": 8
    }, {
      "id": "Joly",
      "group": 8
    }, {
      "id": "Grantaire",
      "group": 8
    }, {
      "id": "MotherPlutarch",
      "group": 9
    }, {
      "id": "Gueulemer",
      "group": 4
    }, {
      "id": "Babet",
      "group": 4
    }, {
      "id": "Claquesous",
      "group": 4
    }, {
      "id": "Montparnasse",
      "group": 4
    }, {
      "id": "Toussaint",
      "group": 5
    }, {
      "id": "Child1",
      "group": 10
    }, {
      "id": "Child2",
      "group": 10
    }, {
      "id": "Brujon",
      "group": 4
    }, {
      "id": "Mme.Hucheloup",
      "group": 8
    }],
    "links": [{
      "source": "Napoleon",
      "target": "Myriel",
      "value": 1
    }, {
      "source": "Mlle.Baptistine",
      "target": "Myriel",
      "value": 8
    }, {
      "source": "Mme.Magloire",
      "target": "Myriel",
      "value": 10
    }]
  }

  var link = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line");

  var node = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 2.5)
    .on('click', clicked);

  node.append("title")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.id;
    });

  simulation
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
    .links(graph.links);

  function ticked() {
    link
      .attr("x1", function(d) {
        return d.source.x;
      })
      .attr("y1", function(d) {
        return d.source.y;
      })
      .attr("x2", function(d) {
        return d.target.x;
      })
      .attr("y2", function(d) {
        return d.target.y;
      });

    node
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return d.y;
      });
  }

  var active = d3.select(null);

  function clicked(d) {

    if (active.node() === this){
      active.classed("active", false);
      return reset();
    }
    
    active = d3.select(this).classed("active", true);

    svg.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .call(zoom.transform,
        d3.zoomIdentity
        .translate(width / 2, height / 2)
        .scale(8)
        .translate(-(+active.attr('cx')), -(+active.attr('cy')))
      );
  }

  function reset() {
    svg.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .call(zoom.transform,
        d3.zoomIdentity
        .translate(0, 0)
        .scale(1)
      );
  }

  function zoomed() {
    g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
  }
</script>
```