# How can I avoid d3.zoom translate on first zoom or pan?

Tags: d3.js

I try to make an orgchart with zoom and paning. To do so I need to call .nodeSize which translate my  "root" to (0,0). Then I re-translate it by width/2 and it's ok. But when I implement d3.zoom, my "root" go back to (0,0)... How can i avoid this behavior ?

Here is the code concerned :

```
var svg = d3.select("#svg1").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
  svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
  }))
  .append('g').attr("transform","translate(" + width / 2 + "," + 0 + ")");
```

Thanks for reading.

EDIT : I did a JSFiddle so you can try  my current code. Don't pay attention to big traingles (I don't have them on my real project) =>
https://jsfiddle.net/rhz1n8m4/12/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the zoom to a node below the `width/2` transform.

Rename your vars to reflect what they contain: `svg` does not contain the `svg` element.

```
var svg = d3.select("#svg1").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
.call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () { svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform); }))
.append('g').attr("transform","translate(" + width / 2 + "," + 0 + ")")
.append('g');
```

**Edit**

@Zoom proposed a solution with `transform-origin` (see edit history), clearly a workaround. Better is to re-arrange the `g` elements.

Apply the zoom to a node **above** the `width/2` transform.

```
  var svg1 = d3.select("#svg1")
    .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
    .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () { svg1.attr("transform", d3.event.transform); }))
    .append('g');
  var svg = svg1.append('g')
      .attr("transform","translate(" + width / 2 + "," + 0 + ")");
```

Read the d3-zoom doc page and you might find a different solution that does not use a `transform` attribute.

Comment: THANK YOU! It works, I will analyse carefully why, I'm totally new to JavaScript AND D3. Thank you again for your time and your answer !

Comment: Just to be complete, this works BUT the center of the zoom seems to be translated by width/2 now. I will inestigate !

Comment: The answer had been edited, adding ".style("transform-origin", "-50% 0 0")" fix zoom issues. 100% working now

Comment: @Zoom: there is a much more elegant solution to this initial translate problem.

Comment: It's more than possible indeed ^^ I did with my few knowledge. What is this solution ?

Comment: Indeed ! Thank you very much, my method was really ugly ^^ (and I knew it)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`zoom.transform()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#zoom_transform) to set the initial translation of the zoom.

You can also check [this Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41918012/d3-zoom-function-issues-in-v4) for a usage example. So in your case, you would do

```js
var svg = d3.select("#svg1").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
        svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
    }))
  .call(d3.zoom().transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(width / 2, 0))
  .append("g").attr("transform","translate(" + width / 2 + "," + 0 + ")");
```