# zoom is applying translate(0,0) scale(1) on first mouse left click event

Tags: d3.js

I designed a codepan which uses D3 V4 Tree layout. First left click anywhere on svg calling zoomed function and applying translate(0,0) scale(1) to tag "points_g" (line 595 in codepan). this shifting creates discrepancy between x-scale values and node values.(non-leaf node values represent x-axis values).

Why is it shifting svg to translate(0,0) scale(1) on first left click without even without mouse or touchpad movement. 
https://codepen.io/ankit-jo14/pen/qQXweG

React here is just calling this.createcluster(). All D3 stuff/render is done by createcluster method only.

```
/*
 * A simple React component
 */
let data = {
    "nodeName": "node3",
    "parentName": null,
    "height": 0.9855515016920474,
    "children": [{
        "nodeName": "PI101404A",
        "parentName": "node3",
        "height": 0,
        "children": null
    }, {
        "nodeName": "node2",
        "parentName": "node3",
        "height": 0.7673460120162033,
        "children": [{
            "nodeName": "PI103079",
            "parentName": "node2",
            "height": 0,
            "children": null
        }, {
            "nodeName": "node1",
            "parentName": "node2",
            "height": 0.6499660584648042,
            "children": [{
                "nodeName": "PI123440",
                "parentName": "node1",
                "height": 0,
                "children": null
            }, {
                "nodeName": "node0",
                "parentName": "node1",
                "height": 0.3968508997429306,
                "children": [{
                    "nodeName": "PI124871",
                    "parentName": "node0",
                    "height": 0,
                    "children": null
                }, {
                    "nodeName": "PI131531",
                    "parentName": "node0",
                    "height": 0,
                    "children": null
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
};
class HCluster extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // Don't call this.setState() here!
        this.state = {
            svgwidth: 1000,
            svgheight: 1000
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.createcluster();
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.createcluster();
    }

    createcluster() {
        let pcamargin = {
            top: 20,
            right: 150,
            bottom: 20,
            left: 30
        };
        let width = this.state.svgwidth;
        let height = this.state.svgheight - 20;

        let root = d3.hierarchy(this.props.data);
        // height and width are opposite of dim as it 90 degree roteted.
        var tree = d3
            .cluster()
            .size([height - pcamargin.bottom, width - pcamargin.right]);

        tree(root);

        console.log(root);

        let cluster = d3.select(this.refs.anchor);
        cluster.selectAll("*").remove();
        cluster.attr("width", this.state.svgwidth);
        cluster.attr("height", this.state.svgheight);

        // create a clipping region
        cluster
            .append("defs")
            .append("clipPath")
            .attr("id", "clip")
            .append("rect")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

        // create scale objects
        let xScale = d3
            .scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, 1])
            .range([width - pcamargin.left, 0]);
        // create axis objects
        let xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(20, "s");

        // Draw Axis
        let gX = cluster
            .append("g")
            .attr(
                "transform",
                "translate(" +
                pcamargin.left +
                "," +
                (this.state.svgheight - pcamargin.bottom) +
                ")"
            )
            .call(xAxis);

        let zoom = d3
            .zoom()
            .extent([
                [0, 0],
                [width, height]
            ])
            .on("zoom", zoomed);

        cluster
            .append("rect")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .style("fill", "none")
            .style("pointer-events", "all")
            .attr(
                "transform",
                "translate(" + pcamargin.left + "," + pcamargin.top + ")"
            )
            .call(zoom);

        // Draw Datapoints
        var points_g = cluster
            .append("g")
            .attr(
                "transform",
                "translate(" + pcamargin.left + "," + pcamargin.top + ")"
            )
            .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
            .classed("points_g", true);

        let links = points_g
            .selectAll(".link")
            .data(root.descendants().slice(1))
            .enter()
            .append("path");

        links.each(function (d) {
            //       console.log("d.y before " +d.data.name +" "+ d.y + " height" + d.data.height );

            //d.y = d.depth * 120 + (d.children ? d.data.height : height - 160 );
            //d.y = (height/2) - d.data.height;
            return (d.y = xScale(d.data.height));
            //    console.log("d.y after " + d.y);
        });

        links.attr("class", "link").attr("d", function (d) {
            return (
                "M" +
                d.y +
                "," +
                d.x +
                "L" +
                d.parent.y +
                "," +
                d.x +
                " " +
                d.parent.y +
                "," +
                d.parent.x
            );
        });

        let nodes = points_g
            .selectAll(".node")
            .data(root.descendants())
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", function (d) {
                return "node" + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf");
            })
            .attr("transform", function (d) {
                return (
                    "rotate( 0 " +
                    d.y +
                    "," +
                    d.x +
                    ")" +
                    " translate(" +
                    d.y +
                    "," +
                    d.x +
                    ")"
                );
            });

        nodes.append("circle").attr("r", 2.5);

        nodes
            .append("text")
            .attr("x", 10)
            .attr("y", 2)
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.children ? d.data.height : d.data.name;
            });
        //  width = +svg.attr("width");
        // height = +svg.attr("height");
        // var g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(40,0)");


        function zoomed() {
            console.log("zoomcalled");
            var new_xScale = d3.event.transform.rescaleX(xScale);

            points_g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);

            gX.call(xAxis.scale(new_xScale));
        }
    }
    render() {
        return <svg ref="anchor" />;
    }
}


   /*
 * Render the above component into the div#app
 */

ReactDOM.render(
  <HCluster data={data} />,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

Comment: Same problem as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53206675/9938317

Comment: I appended a "g" inside svg and then appended "points_g". Like
<svg><g><g class="point_g"/></g></svg> and it worked. so translate and tranform is done on points_g and outer g is used for zomming. but I still don't understand the logic.(line 91 in code pan)

Comment: Use DevTools while zooming and you might see how it works